# How to refresh my grid? and How to calculate the amount of time?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, grid

I am trying to create a simple rigid body 2D physics engine.

I was able to create a rectangle image by using four lines and able to manipulate the image according to its angle and position; I can move and rotate it (though I made it possible to rotate I do not use the rotating function since I am unable to comprehend angular momentum theory yet).

The image will fall and bounce back based on simple formula:

```
v(velocity) += a(acceleration)
x += v(velocity)
```

But I have to click a button every time I want execute a movement.

I want it to execute itself automatically and update automatically, I tried to use loop but for some reason program seems to stop during the time it is in loop section. And because I use an infinite loop that will start over and over again, my program just freezes.

Not only this is the problem but also my good friend, who has better knowledge in physics, told me that I should be able to calculate the amount of time if I want to make this engine work properly.

Comment: have you thought about using Threads and or Timer and setting the interval ..?

Comment: Isn't XNA an option? XNA not only provides the methods for automatically refreshing the scenario but is also specifically designed for games, which sounds very much as what your trying to accomplish (note that I'm not saying you're building a game).

Comment: could you post how you have already tried to implement this, while threads & XNA are very good solutions it may be just a simple error which is preventing your loop from completing

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I did not know that there was a comment section here. I have this infinite route.

Comment: while(true) { refresh_lines() } And Yes, I am trying to make a game. I would like to know more about XNA. I never heard of that word before

Comment: As a general guide, when someone asks for code, in this situation, u edit your question and make the edit visible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like DJ KRAZE's comment - use a [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx), and set the interval to however often you want the picture to redraw.  On the timer's `Tick` event, do your redraw.

If you want to know why the simple loop doesn't work, you have to know a little bit about the [Windows message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632590%28VS.85%29.aspx).  For a brief and somewhat inaccurate overview, all of stuff running in your application, it sounds like, is happening on one thread.  Windows uses a message `WM_PAINT`, which goes through the message loop, to make the control paint itself.  It only processes on message at a time.

Where you have your infinite loop, that is happening in the processing of some message.  So this keeps the message loop from processing any messages, including messages for the controls to paint.  So you don't see anything updating in your infinite loop.

Comment: It's about WPF, so I'd rather suggest a `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`, a `System.Threading.Timer` or a `System.Timers.Timer` instead.

Comment: Oops good point, I thought I saw a windows forms tag up there, but clearly I'm going blind.

Comment: This may be because of my lack of profound knowledge, I do not insist to explain since I know it is unlikely for me to understand the differences between just timer and DispatcherTimer but I am surprised to know that there are so many different kinds of timers and so confused

Comment: I cannot find system.windows.Treahding.DispatcherTimer from my library. Is it possible that I do not have that namespace on my computer? I use visual studio c#.

Comment: I got it. System.Windows.Threading is for System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer. OK...

Comment: @user1143720, if this solves your problem, you can vote the answer up by clicking on the up arrow, and accept the answer by clicking on the check mark - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: user1143720's comments make me smile... brings me back to my greenhorn days

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look into [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791), it's a Microsoft platform that facilitates games development, you should go to the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) for information on how to get started.

As for your specific question on refreshing the screen, you can take a look at the [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.update.aspx) and [Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.draw.aspx) methods. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff472340%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)'s a tutorial that, although may not address your specific question, should give you the know-to on how to refresh the screen.